# Polling alternative to Service Broker in SQL Server backplane for SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am attempting to set up SignalR in my web app using SQL Server as a backplane. The only problem is, I am forced to use Azure SQL, and Azure SQL does not support Service Broker, which is required to get updates from the database in my web app.

Is there a way I can run a procedure on an interval on the backend of my app to check for changes, and then send the messages out that way? If I could use Service Broker, my SQL dependency code "would" look something like this:

**Global.asax**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //some other startup code...
        startSqlDependency();
    }

    private void startSqlDependency()
    {
        // Create a dependency connection to the database.
        SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionString);
        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand("select top 2000 * from t_download order by createdate desc", connection))
            {
                SqlCacheDependency dependency =
                    new SqlCacheDependency(command);
                int numberOfMinutes = 3;
                DateTime expires =
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(numberOfMinutes);

                Response.Cache.SetExpires(expires);
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
                Response.AddCacheDependency(dependency);
                connection.Open();
                //more logic here to send messages...
            }
        }
    }
```

But since I cannot use SQL dependency, is there a way that I can use a polling mechanism? Maybe something like this?

```
    private void startSqlDependency()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand("select top 2000 * from t_download order by createdate desc", connection))
            {
                //logic here to send detect changes and send messages...
            }
        }
    }
```

And how could I get that to reliably run on an interval in my app service?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you could use -

Setup a Timer (example):

```
public class GetMyData
{
    static Timer YourTimer = new Timer()

public static void YourBroadcaster()
    {
        try
        {
            YourTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent_YourDataBroadcaster);
            YourTimer.Interval = 30000;
            YourTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void OnTimedEvent_YourBroadcaster(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHub>();

        //Your SQL Query here


        //Send data out to clients
        hubContext.Clients.All.yourClientMethod()
    }
}
```

Another option is based on when/how your data is updated. If you control the updates  in your code then you can trigger an update to your client(s).

1. Data update from client or other source
2. SQL Query to update
3. If update was successful then query your updated data
4. Broadcast the data out to client(s)

I'm sure there are other options. Hopefully that helps though.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I like the idea of the timer, actually. But I like the idea of updating when the data is updated. That is what I am attempting to do with SignalR. The problem with that is that the data is updated by a webjob in Azure, and the clients need to be updated in a separate Azure app service (web app). There doesn't appear to be an easy way to make my webjob to update my web app clients, unless I am using Sql Server. But that also requires service broker, which Azure SQL doesn't support. The polling is to try to get around that limitation.

Comment: I have not worked in Azure yet but a thought occurred that I use in my on premise setup. Can you make the Azure webjob a client of your Azure app? This way the client is like any other client but send a message when data has been updated to your SignalR hub. The hub can run the sql query and then broadcast to your clients.